# Perforce command line head revision file

Tags: command-line, perforce

What is the command line syntax to check whether this workspace currently has the latest revision of a certain file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command:

```
p4 sync -n
```

will preview the sync operation. This will tell you which files would be updated were you to use the actual command.

The command:

```
p4 have [file]
```

will tell you the version of the file you currently have. This coupled with:

```
p4 fstat -T "headRev" [file]
```

which tells you the head revision number, will tell you whether you have the latest version or not.

It's worth noting that all Perforce commands have a preview option that tell you what they *would* do. This allows you to verify you've got the correct command without fear of corrupting your workspace or depot.